# Setting up SqlServer in ASP.Net Core - GetRequiredService causes error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I get an error in Startup.cs when I add the sql database and I'm at a lose. I enter:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
```

well I actually get it from the program.cs, but the error originates from the line above. Caller:

```
var context = services.GetRequiredService<ModelContext>();
```

The error message is:

```
Method 'Clone' 
in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' 
from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
```

The error source is:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Full Error Message:

```
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HResult -2146233054 int
        HelpLink    null    string
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
        Message "Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation."  string
        Source  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"   string
        StackTrace  "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer\r\n   at FltCandidates.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\\Users\\garry\\source\\repos\\FltCandidates\\FltCandidates\\Startup.cs:line 35\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at FltCandidates.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Users\\garry\\source\\repos\\FltCandidates\\FltCandidates\\Program.cs:line 26"    string
+       TargetSite  {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}   System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
        TypeName    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension"   string
```

My .CSProj contains:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated

The question was answered in the comments below the question. SqlServer ended up being installed, but for some reason wasn't showing in NuGet. As soon as I tried to install the newer version of sqlserver it forced NuGet to update the "invisible" already installed SqlServer.

Comment: Is it correct adding CandidateContext and trying to get ModelContext?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, they were all CandidateContext, I thought I'd renamed them all to ModelContext. I edited them in the text as I thought It'd make it easier to see it in a more standard way.

Comment: Okay, the problem probably is with [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) nuget package version. You are trying to use older 1.1.5.0 version with newer version of EF Core. Try update to 2.0.1

Comment: I was using the NuGet Manager and "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver" never showed up as installed or in updates... but I did have "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Tools" installed. After installing "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver 2.0.1" it showed that it was updating 1.1.5... so for some reason it was installed but wasn't showing. If copy your comment into an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: And is it working after the update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the looks of the `.CSproj` file, yours is a .Net Core 2  project that hasn't [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) packaged installed.  You can tell because you are missing a line similar to:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
```

This package is also a dependency for [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Desing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design/) which its current version is 1.1.5 and will install the same version number for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. The problem with this is that the [`Clone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.internal.sqlserveroptionsextension.clone?view=efcore-2.0) method exists only in Entity Framework Core 2. That being said, you should install or update `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`package to a `2.0.1` version. This version is compatible with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Desing`

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question was answered in the comments below the question. SqlServer ended up being installed, but for some reason wasn't showing in NuGet. As soon as I tried to install the newer version of sqlserver it forced NuGet to update the "invisible" already installed SqlServer.